# how to get unique values in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i want to get latest 10 unique records whose last 12 characters should be unique.
 sample data

json data

[{"timestamp":"2017-03-20T05:27:01.688Z","dataFrame":"ACnrAAAAAAAAAAA=","fcnt":165,"port":3,"rssi":-85,"snr":7,"sf_used":12,"id":1489987621688,"decrypted":true},{"timestamp":"2017-03-20T05:27:41.675Z","dataFrame":"ACntAAAAAAAAAAA=","fcnt":169,"port":3,"rssi":-85,"snr":9,"sf_used":12,"id":1489987661675,"decrypted":true},..

```
AGMDAQo1/wSsCPU=
AGMEAQo1/wSsCPU=
AGMFAQo1/wSsCPU=
AGMGAQo1/wSsCPU=
AGMHAQo1/wSsCPU=
ASHAAQo2FgSsBxc=
```

getting  output like this , but it should only be one because last 12 characters are same.

```
AGMDAQo1/wSsCPU=,
AGMEAQo1/wSsCPU=,
AGMFAQo1/wSsCPU=
```

desired output

```
AGMDAQo1/wSsCPU=
ASHAAQo2FgSsBxc=
```

code

```
 var Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);
                    var items = Pirs.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA="))
                                             .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame)
                                             .Select(g => g.First())
                                             .OrderByDescending(a => a.timestamp)
                                             .Take(10);
```

model

```
 public class AssetDetail
        {
            public long id { get; set; }
            public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
            public string dataFrame { get; set; }
            public long fcnt { get; set; }
            public int port { get; set; }
            public int rssi { get; set; }
            public string snr { get; set; }
            public string sf_used { get; set; }
            public bool decrypted { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: i want the unique values in dataframe. last 12 characters should be unique. in one data frame i have 3 values in that 2 values should be unique. those 2 values are in last 12 characters.

Comment: I get that part but I am asking what is wrong with your query: what is it returning that you don't like?

Comment: i have updated my question with my output which im getting.

Comment: See @granit answer. It should solve the issue.

Comment: yes its working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `a.dataFrame.Substring(a.dataFrame.Length - 12)` inside the GroupBy function to group by the AssetDetails that have the same 12 characters at the end on their dataFrame property.

```
var Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);
var items = Pirs.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA="))
                                 .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame.Substring(a.dataFrame.Length - 12))
                                 .Select(g => g.First())
                                 .OrderByDescending(a => a.timestamp)
                                 .Take(10);
```

There is no need to use the Distinct() function if you are using GroupBy()

Answer (score 1):

Use `Distinct()`:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);
                    var items = Pirs.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA="))
                                             .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame)
                                             .Select(g => g.First())
                                             .Distinct()
                                             .OrderByDescending(a => a.timestamp)
                                             .Take(10);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: distinct in the sense i need last 12 characters should be unique in the data frame

Comment: No distinct is not needed because the results are grouped so they are distinct already.